# как сделать чтоб на моем сайте при нажатии кнопки Start она меняла цвет до того момента пока не нажму на нее еще раз

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let milsec = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let displayMilsec = 0;
let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;
let interval = null;
let status = "stopped";

function stopWatch() {
  milsec++;
  if (milsec / 10 === 1) {
    milsec = 0;
    seconds++;
    if (seconds / 60 === 1) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
      if (minutes / 60 === 1) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (milsec < 10) {
    displayMilsec = milsec.toString();
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
  } else {
    displaySeconds = seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
  } else {
    displayMinutes = minutes;
  }
  if (hours < 10) {
    displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
  } else {
    displayHours = hours;
  }
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds + "." + displayMilsec;
}

function startStop() {
  if (status === "stopped") {
    interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 100);
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
    status = "started";
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
    status = "stopped";
  }
}

function reset() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  milsec = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00.0";
  document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
  status = "stopped";
}
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 48%;
  top: 46%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.a1 {
  background: #4beb23;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.a2 {
  background: #bd2d2d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="display">
      00:00:00.0
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="a1" id="startStop" onclick="startStop()">Start</button>
      <button class="a2" id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.oncontextmenu = cmenu;

    function cmenu() {
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Кто менял цвет, на какой, до какого, какие цвета, больше информации пожалуйста

Comment: Кнопка "старт" во время нажатия запускает секундомер и превращается "стоп", но мне также надо чтобы после нажатияя меняла цвет на ораньжевый до того момента пока не нажму на эту кнопку снова или не нажму на "reset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так..

```js
let milsec = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let displayMilsec = 0;
let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;
let interval = null;
let status = "stopped";
let start = document.getElementById("startStop");

function stopWatch() {
  milsec++;
  if (milsec / 10 === 1) {
    milsec = 0;
    seconds++;
    if (seconds / 60 === 1) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
      if (minutes / 60 === 1) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (milsec < 10) {
    displayMilsec = milsec.toString();
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
  } else {
    displaySeconds = seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
  } else {
    displayMinutes = minutes;
  }
  if (hours < 10) {
    displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
  } else {
    displayHours = hours;
  }
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds + "." + displayMilsec;
}

function startStop() {
  if (status === "stopped") {
    interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 100);
    start.innerHTML = "Stop";
    start.style.background = 'orange';
    status = "started";
  } else {
    start.style.background = '#4beb23';
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
    status = "stopped";
  }
}

function reset() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  milsec = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00.0";
  document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
  status = "stopped";
  start.style.background = '#4beb23';

}
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 48%;
  top: 46%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.a1 {
  background: #4beb23;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.a2 {
  background: #bd2d2d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="display">
      00:00:00.0
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="a1" id="startStop" onclick="startStop()">Start</button>
      <button class="a2" id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.oncontextmenu = cmenu;

    function cmenu() {
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Чтобы "сбросить" стиль который назначили, просто передайте пустое значение)

Comment: @De.Minov Это для примера вдруг светофор захочется)

Comment: Ну тогда ладно)